# Solve equation using combinations of integers from 0 to 9 in Maple

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Display answers for $x$ using all combinations of $0$ to $9$ integers for $a$ and $b$

$\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}=\dfrac{a^{2}}{s^2}+\dfrac{b^{2}}{t^{2}}$

The values for $s$ and $t$ are known values and must be entered by the user

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share what you have tried? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I could do for you is as follows, however, I couldn't insert proper codes to the program till it takes $s$ and $t$ from keyboard automatically. I think this program deserves to be considered. I assumed that $s=2$ and $t=5$ as you see:

```
  [> for i from 0 to 9 do
        for j from 0 to 9 do 
        c[i, j] := solve(1/x^2 = (1/4)*i^2+(1/25)*j^2, {x}) 
        od;
    od; 
  [> eval(c);
```

For example while $s=2,t=5$, we can call some of the result:

```
  [> c[9,9];
               {x = -(10/261)*sqrt(29)}, {x = (10/261)*sqrt(29)}
  [> c[3,8];
               {x = -(10/481)*sqrt(481)}, {x = (10/481)*sqrt(481)}
```

Comment: $\uparrow_\uparrow^+$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for the arrows. Just think upward. :)

Comment: Yes, indeed! ;-)

Comment: @BabakS. Thank you for your help, much appreciated!